How to Apply a Pre-trained Jigsaw Puzzle Model for Transfer Learning on Larger Images?
I’ve read the article titled Unsupervised Learning of Visual Representations by Solving Jigsaw Puzzles.
In this article, the authors create jigsaw puzzles and train a model to solve them. The process involves starting with an original image of size 256x256, cropping a 225x225 frame from it, then dividing that frame into 9 tiles of 75x75. Each tile is further randomly cropped to 64x64 before being used for training.
My question is: How can this model, which takes nine small images (9 tiles of 64x64), be used in transfer learning? We cannot directly feed a 256x256 image into this model. Should we crop nine 64x64 patches from our image, feed them into the pre-trained model, and then build our new network on top of it?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
